# Creating a spell checking function in python (Check misspellings)

Tags: python, function

I have a file with a few lines of English sentences.
Some of these words are misspelled and I am looking to construct a function that:

1. Detects spelling mistakes and displays them in a list.
2. After finding the wrong words, write them correctly and return them to the output.

for example
input: x = "This is the **lnguage** of **Pithon**"
Result: = Wrong words: ['lnguage','pithon']

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you provide some code for us to work with? State any difficulties you had in the code that you've written and also provide an input and an expected output.

Comment: Almost nothing and I am not even allowed to use the functions built into Python itself

Comment: Check my answer. I will add some proper working code soon but this is a starting point

Comment: Thank you, I'm also trying to code to get the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GingerIt API with python library like this

**IN TERMINAL**

```
pip install gingerit
```

**FOR CODE**

```
from gingerit.gingerit import GingerIt
text = input("Enter text to be corrected")
result = GingerIt().parse(text)
corrections = result['corrections']
correctText = result['result']

print("Correct Text:",correctText)
print()
print("CORRECTIONS")
for d in corrections:
  print("________________")  
  print("Previous:",d['text'])  
  print("Correction:",d['correct'])   
  print("Definiton:",d['definition'])
```

Test it here

https://repl.it/@SiddharthAgraw2/StackOverFlowQueries

Comment: As if it does not work properly
  Did not show anything in the output

Comment: Of course, when I printed the result, it showed me this:{'text': 'ths is the tutorial pithon to make a grammr and spelling proram', 'result': 'This is the tutorial python to make a grammar and spelling program', 'corrections': [{'start':.////////////////////It continues

Comment: As I said, this is the starting point, you need to modify it. I am adding some working code in a minute

Comment: I have updated the code. Since this answer worked, you should accept it by clicking on the tick option and give it an upvote

Comment: I tried, but it just didn't detect any misspellings at all.
  Only the first word of the word started capitalizing the text

Comment: Could you join me on that repl. Change the string in that code to what you are using. If you do not want to use repl, just send me the snippet u are using

Comment: I see what you mean. The things is, grammar detecting is not easy. Its really tough work which needs big ML models which are really complicated. Only some companies provided free access to their APIs and they are not the best in the buisness. You can train your own ML model or you can stick with a basic grammar check. If you need to publish this, you should consider spending money to buy service to a good API

Comment: I need your email

Comment: Not so big
  Just an exercise

Comment: siddharthagrawal2006@gmail.com

Comment: Check your email